# How to target a specific instance in azure webapp service

Tags: azure, curl, azure-web-app-service

Let's say that I have 8 instances running of one webapp service. I would like to target a specific instance when sending a request to API (for example for some debugging purposes). I cannot use ARR affinity cookie because I turned off this option to increase the performance of my API. Is there some other way to target a specific instance while keeping the ARR affinity options tuned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some other way to target a specific instance while keeping the ARR affinity options tuned off?

No, you could **only use ARR Affinity** to specify instance id and point to related instance. For more details about route request to specific instance in multi instance pool you could refer to this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-app-service-routing-request-specific-instance-thangavelu).

Comment: Hm, didn't test it but shouldn't it be possible to just specify the HTTP header (I think it was `X-Instance-Id´) in the request?

Comment: I tried to specify the instance id in both X-Azure-Instance-Id and X-Instance-Id. 
It did not work for me when calling azure web app service. Maybe it works with Azure VMs?

Comment: @MateuszCiezczak It _should_ work if you set the ARR cookie in a `fetch` request - this is how Kudu (at `yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net`) works to allow you to select specific instances.